# how to replace group value using regex in c# .net

Tags: c#, .net, regex

I have a string like

```
string s= "I WAS born in AMERICA on december 1978.";
```

Now I want to convert ***december*** to ***December*** using regex

I have used below incomplete regex

```
s=Regex.Replace(s,(january|february|march|April|may|june|july|august|september|October|november|December),CultreInfo.InvariantCulture.TextInfo.ToTitleCase(?????),RegexOption.IgnoreCase);
```

What I have to write here (?????) so that I can get below output

```
s= "I WAS born in AMERICA on December 1978.";
```

Is there any other way which I can apply??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at [`regex.replace`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms149475(v=vs.110).aspx) documentation, I notice that you'd have to use a callback function.

So write a function:

```
function CustomReplace( Match m ) {
    return CultreInfo.InvariantCulture.TextInfo.ToTitleCase(m.Groups[1].Value)
}
```

and pass it as the 3rd argument:

```
s = Regex.Replace(
    s,
    "(january|february|march|April|may|june|july|august|september|October|november|December)",
    CustomReplace,
    RegexOption.IgnoreCase
);
```

Answer (score 0):

Using a [named capture](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bs2twtah.aspx#named_matched_subexpression) and inline [MatchEvaluator](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.matchevaluator.aspx):

```
string s = "I WAS born in AMERICA on december 1978.";
s = Regex.Replace(
    s,
    "(?<months>january|february|march|April|may|june|july|august|september|October|november|December)",
    new MatchEvaluator(
        match => CultureInfo
                .InvariantCulture
                .TextInfo
                .ToTitleCase(match.Groups["months"].Value)
    ),
    RegexOptions.IgnoreCase
);
```